# Why main() is run twice at android device start up?

Tags: linux-kernel, startup, android, init

I'm a newbie to this subject, and I'm trying to optimize the boot time of of a specific android smartphone model with Android 5.1.1 (Lollipop) and Kernel version 3.10.49. By calling the `ERROR()` macro inside the `int main(int argc, char **argv)` function (declared inside `system/core/init/init.c`), We got messages which can be read through `dmesg`. At the moment I observed that the same message which was thrown by `main` was recorded twice in the `dmesg` log. Is it telling that the `main()` was run twice? Is there a reason for it?